# Передача строки по ссылке С#

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо инициализировать новый экземпляр класса и передать через аргумент строковое значение.
В дальнейшем при изменении строкового значения из первоначального класса, он автоматом должен меняться в созданном новом классе.
Пробовал передавать значение по ссылке следующим образом:

```
class MyClass1
{
    MyClass2 class2;
    string s;

    public MyClass1()
    {
        class2 = new MyClass2(ref s);
    }
}

class MyClass2
{
    string s;

    public MyClass2(ref s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

В данном случае, если меняем s в экземпляре класса MyClass1 - она не меняется (так понимаю из-за следующего присваивания - this.s = s;).

Считал, что раз string является ссылочным типом, вопросов не должно было возникнуть, но и добавление ref не привело ни к чему.

Как можно решить этот момент меньшей кровью?

Comment: Передавать не саму строку, а объект содержащий эту строку. Какой-нибудь StringHolder.

Comment: @vitidev, была, конечно, такая мысль, но думал, есть какое-то решение без лишних объектов. если никто интереснее вариант не предложит, скорее всего так и сделаю)

Comment: Вы не сможете использовать ref field и это ставит крест на ref. Можно нарушить иммутабельность string, но лучше обертка.

Comment: @vitidev, мне не обязательно вообще использовать ref, я просто посчитал, что в этом случае будет передаваться параметр по ссылке

Comment: При передаче значимого типа **копируется** значение, при передаче ссылочного - **копируется** ссылка на значение. ref позволяет сослаться на память, где лежит передаваемое значение (а для ссылочных типов это сама ссылка). Так что вы правильно смотрите в сторону ref. И внутри конструктора MyClass2 вы можете сделать s="foo" и это повляет на MyClass1, как вам и нужно. Но поля не умеют в ref и при  this.s = s; происходит **копирование** ссылки и дальше вы уже работаете с копией. И если вам нужно сохранить строку как поле класса - только враппер.

Comment: @vitidev, cпасибо за развернутый комментарий!